# Tiktok followers list and implementation of "Follow on tiktok" outside tiktok app

Tags: reactjs, tiktok, tiktok-api

I want to implement a feature in my react app "Follow on tiktok" without actually redirecting the user to tiktok app. I want to follow someone on tiktok directly through my app. is it possible?
if not, I can still manage this thing if the there is some way to get the followers/following data from my tiktok account using tiktok apis.?

Can someone help me out there.

Comment: It maybe possible but the user somehow need to login. Of course your user won't type their tiktok password in your app. Also you need to use their private api and you need to reverse engineer tiktok application to see how their auth flow is done. And why do you want to do something like this?

Comment: yes, user is logging in tiktok through my app and i am getting his/her access token as well.

Comment: Then you are stealing their account.

Comment: I think, that's not true, when ever they want to connect their tiktok account with my app, I am prompting the data i will use from their tiktok account and taking their consent. After their consent and permissions, Titkok is giving me their data.
i.e. when someone login  with gmail, their basic data is shared with the third party app.

Comment: No that is different between linking your tiktok account and tiktok login in in your application. Linking account is you will prompt your user to redirect to real tiktok login page then tiktok will give you public api to use with the user token but you will never know what is the user password.

Comment: I don't know tiktok support that or no.